# How to build standalone SDL project with visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exe

I'm getting ready to enter Ludum Dare this evening, and I'm getting really frustrated because I'm unable to build my project into a standalone .exe.

I feel like this question has been asked at least 100 times but none of the answers I'm finding are helping me out at all... I don't really understand what static linking is or how to do it, and that doesn't even seem like the solution to my problem; I don't mind if I'm shipping out a bunch of .dll files with my program, I just want the program to run on its own so I can submit it at the end of the competition.

Basically, my visual studio (2010 express) configuration follows exactly [LazyFoo's tutorial on setting it up](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php). Everything runs fine on both debug and release configurations when I start the program from visual studio, but when I navigate into the Debug or Release folders of the project and try to run the .exe, the programs break with an error about `abort()` being called, or they give me the error "X program has stopped working."

I'm including all of my DLLs in the same folder as the executables are being placed, and the game runs perfectly fine from inside VS, but I just can't seem how to figure out how to compile it as a standalone .exe (or even including a folder full of dlls) without it falling apart.

Can someone give me a pretty precise way to get this working? Any help would be great.

Comment: It is just insane, a microsoft dll of the same source can have at least six incompatible derivations (are there more?).

Comment: @DieterLücking: Well, it is called "DLL hell" for a reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an EXE, then your program is compiling. Most likely in debug mode, the program is running using a specific directory as the *current working directory* (CWD), but when you run it as standalone, the CWD is different.

The CWD affects both the DLL that can be loaded as well as the search of any file that uses a relative path (that is, not starting with a [back]slash). That is probably your problem: textures, graphics, configuration files, fonts...

My advise is to set the CWD in the debugging runs (there is an option for that) to be exactly the same than that of the EXE, that is the default when you run the EXE. Then you will be able to debug your crash.

Comment: Agh, thank you. I feel so silly, I hadn't added my assets to the directory the EXE was being built in, so my issue was just that the images weren't being loaded properly. Thanks for your help!